# Best Way To Lookup Items In Multi-Dimensional List in Python

Tags: python

I know this is "simple", but I can't figure this out or find help on this and it's driving me crazy. I want to make a multi dimensional list that has multiple values, like 3 values for each row for example, and I want to be able to find out any of the row's information based on a given value.

For example, if I have the following data:

Name: Dog, Color: Brown, Behavior: Happy
Name: Cat, Color: Black, Behavior: Sad 
Name: Bird, Color: Green, Behavior: Energetic

So I make a list like this:

```
theList = []

theList = [{"dog","brown","happy" }, {"cat","black", "sad"}, {"bird","green", "energetic"} ]
```

How can I find out the information for something based on a value? For example, I want to find out the color of the dog? How would I search the list for "dog" and find out what the value is for the second thing (value [1] within the list section that contains "dog"?

Or is it easier to do a multi-dimensional dictionary for this?

Comment: A dictionary is a textbook solution for this use case.

Comment: hmm ok. i know with a dictionary, usually it has a "key" and a "value", so it feels like a 2 dimensional array to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really depends on what your intention is. As pointed out by @ViníciusAguiar you could use the animal as a key in the dictionary but this only makes sense if `name` is your primary lookup and you don't have multiple `dog`s with different colours and behaviours.

Alternatively, if this really is a table that you want to ask multiple questions of then a list of dicts maybe the appropriate structure, e.g.:

```
In []:
data = [{"name":"dog", "colour":"brown", "behaviour":"happy"},
        {"name":"cat", "colour":"black", "behaviour":"sad"},
        {"name":"bird", "colour":"green", "behaviour":"energetic"} ]

[d['colour'] for d in data if d['name'] == 'dog']

Out[]:
['brown']
```

Here is the equivalent `for` loop:

```
In []:
result = []
for d in data:
    if d['name'] == 'dog':
         result.append(d['colour'])
result

Out[]:
['brown']
```

But you can also ask other questions like which animals are `green`:

```
In []:
[d['name'] for d in data if d['colour'] == 'green']

Out[]:
['bird']
```

If you can also use third party libraries then there is `pandas`, which is good at handling table data, e.g.:

```
In []:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

Out[]:
   name colour  behaviour
0   dog  brown      happy
1   cat  black        sad
2  bird  green  energetic

In []:
df[df['name']=='dog']['colour']

Out[]:
0    brown
```

Comment: for this statement: [d['colour'] for d in data if d['name'] == 'dog'] , can you write out the "long" way to write it out? like what is the original way you are writing it out, i am a little confused by the shortcut you are utilzing there for your python code, if that makes sense, btw this did work, just want to make sure i understand how that code actually works, i'm confused on the d variable and how you just wrote the loop right after

Comment: It's called a [*list comprehension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension), a very useful construct in many languages. For instructional purposes, I've added an equivalent for loop above.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the name of the pet as a `key` in dictionary:

```
myDict = {  "dog": {"Color":"brown","Behaviour":"happy"},
            "cat": {"Color":"black","Behaviour":"sad"},
            "bird": {"Color":"green","Behaviour":"energetic"}}
```

---

> For example, I want to find out the color of the dog?

```
>>> myDict["dog"]["Color"]
'brown'
```